# Does the 1500 visits per day metric apply during private beta?

Tags: support

For Stack Exchange staff. Does the 1500 visit per day benchmark apply during private beta? This seems very high given the site is closed to non members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those goals are the earmarks of a *healthy* site in a steady-state of full growth, so no… they aren't really indicative of what we would typically expect to see during a limited private beta.